# unable to add words to an arabic line after going down in UITextVIew

Tags: ios, swift, textview

What happened is the following in UITextView: I wrote the first word, went 2 lines down, wrote a third word, when I got back to the first word, to continue writing or editing or deleting, it only edited 1 letter and automatically dropped down to the third line. so I can't edit the first line.
any help would be appreciated[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHcjk.jpg)

Comment: I think issue in your textView delegate method's code.

Comment: I'm just using the following:  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        delegate?.advertiseDescriptionTextView(self, didUpdateText: textView.text)
    } nothing else

Comment: it seems yes, ur right, thanks